# Handling "some of your tests did a full page reload" in Angular/Karma testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-routing

I have an Angular component where I can create new entities (new users) using a service that ultimately POSTs to the server. I want to issue a redirect after the user was created, and test that the redirect occurs. I believe that I am correctly using the `RouterTestingModule`.

This is both a **routed** and **routing** component. **Routed** because `/users/:id` triggers the edit for user ID `:id` (while `/users/new` is supposed to set up the form to create a new user). **Routing** because at the end of the action I am supposed to navigate to somewhere else.

Here is some code:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-user',
  templateUrl: './form-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-user.component.scss']
})
export class FormUserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public userForm = this.fb.group({
                    ............
    });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {
  }

  submitForm($event: any): void {
    const usr: CreateUserDto = {
      ...
    }
    const userId = this.userForm.get('id')?.value;

    if (!!userId) {
      this.userService.updateUser(userId!, usr)
        .subscribe({
          next: _ => {
            this.router.navigate(['users']);
          },
          error: err => {
            console.error(err);
            this.router.navigate(['users']);
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.userService.createUser(usr)
        .pipe(
          map(response => response.headers.get('Location')),
          map(location => location?.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)),
          switchMap(location => !!location ? of(location) : throwError(() => 'No location available'))
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: userId => {
            this.router.navigate(['users', userId]);
          },
          error: err => {
            console.error(err);
            this.router.navigate(['users']);
          }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, once I have created a new user I will redirect to `/users/${id}` in order to display user data and switch the form into edit mode. I use the `router.navigate` method.

In my tests:

```js
describe('FormUserComponent', () => {
  let component: FormUserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormUserComponent>;
  let location: Location;
  let userServiceSpy: SpyObj<UserService>;
  let userService: UserService;
   ....
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['createUser', 'updateUser', 'getUser']);
    userService = userServiceSpy;
    userServiceSpy.getUser.withArgs(25).and.returnValue(of(mockUser));
    userServiceSpy.getUser.withArgs(1).and.returnValue(throwError(() => new HttpErrorResponse({status: 404})));
    userServiceSpy.createUser.and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse<void>({
      status: 201,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({Location: '/api/v1/users/1'})
    })));
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FormUserComponent],
      providers: [{provide: UserService, useValue: userService}],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},
        {path: 'users/:id', component: FormUserComponent},
        {path: 'users/new', component: FormUserComponent}
      ]),
        FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormUserComponent);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should submit the form correctly on create', fakeAsync(() => {
    //Ensure we are in "create new user mode" as there are test cases where I need to edit some user
    //location.go('/users/new');
    router.navigate(['users', 'new']);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();

    let form = queryByCss(fixture, 'form');
    ......... // Fill the form

    form.nativeElement.submit(); //Submit the form
    form.triggerEventHandler('submit', {});

    fixture.detectChanges();
    flush();// Have the async pipe do the job

    expect(location.path()).toBe('/users/1'); // Expect that I navigated

  }));

});
```

Test results indicate that they are successful, but the whole test fails because a redirect was issued:

[image: Test results in Webstorm]

Why is a full page reload triggered when the `RotuerTestingModule` is injected into the `TestBed`. Shouldn't Angular handle mocking the `Router` object? Am I missing something about navigating in a way that is Karma-compliant?

In the other questions, I have been reading about this specific error, the redirect was done via a real [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object, but I am using the router facility.

Angular is 12.0.4

[Edit] I am sure that I am using the `SpyLocation` facility in my tests. Looks like the `RouterTestingModule` is correctly injecting the `SpyLocation` as a replacement of `Location`

[image: SpyLocation in debug]

Comment: Isn't the problem that your _test_ directly calls go on the actual Location, _not_ using the router testing module? Check the guidance on routed and routing components in https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios.

Comment: The first line of your test is `location.go(...)`. I don't know if the router testing module is _intended_ to replace Location; it replaces the Angular router components.

Comment: Also, I haven't disclosed that my component is both a routing and routed component. The same component is used to edit ${userId}, so I need both to navigate and to listen for the params change, which is not listed in the code

Comment: What do you mean _"haven't disclosed"_?! We can _see_ it using both ActivatedRoute and navigate on the Router.

Comment: I didn't post the ngOnInit method which listens for `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` in order to collect the user ID

Comment: No, but you did include the contractor parameter property for injection. Please note the general requirement for a [mre].

Comment: Changing `location.go` with `router.navigate` in the test yields the same effect. Now reading the linked article

Comment: please share the solution if you found it